# Please help identify this material that looks like tulle

Tags: fabric, material-identification

I am currently stuck at finding a tulle (like) material as the picture below. I need it to repair torn embroidery.

I have bought, after searching for hundreds of tulles online, 3 different kinds of tulle, and nothing matches. Now I'm not even sure if the material I'm looking for is in fact tulle.

The thread is almost transparent, with a bit of glitter, the holes are tinier than of regular tulle. It does not stretch.

Please help me identify this material or a suitable replacement.

[image: the tulle (like) material]

Answer (score 2):

The best fitting term I could find for this fabric is "**English Netting**" (also called "english net" or "english tulle") or "[**Bobbinet Tulle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobbinet)" (also called "english bobbinet").

Classic Veils has a [great comparison between tulle and englisch netting](https://www.classicveils.com/wedding-veil-fabric-types-colors/) with detailed photos.

Modern tulle usually has a diamond pattern like this:
[image: diamond grid]

English netting has a hexagonal pattern like this:
[image: hexagonal grid]

Bobbinet is woven like this:
[image: woven net with one color of thread running vertically, a second color of thread running diagonally to the left and a third color of thread running diagonally to the right]

The way it's woven makes it non-stretch in all directions and very resistant against tearing compared to other net fabrics. That's why it's the most common background fabric for embroidered net and net lace.

If the thread is transparent and shiny, it's most likely 100% polyester or nylon. If the net should not stretch, it must not have any elastane or spandex content.

Comment: Wow, that is amazing, I'll look it up!